# Problem to run the application showing some error message in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

PS D:\Development\ULTIMAT POS\App POS Backup\UltimatePOS_Flutter_1.7.1\pos> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on M2102J20SG in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\Development\ULTIMAT POS\App POS Backup\UltimatePOS_Flutter_1.7.1\pos\android\app\build.gradle' line: 50
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not get unknown property 'minSdkVersion20' for extension 'flutter' of type FlutterExtension.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              4.6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: android\app\build.gradle' line: 50-----------
minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try change minSdkVersion20 -> minSdkVersion 21 (add space before version)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your App level build.gradle file in android folder and then change

> minSdkVersion 20

to

> minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion

Hope it will solve your error